# Know when all async calls initiated by .each() are done executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm building something using node.js and I'm looping through all `img` tags using jQuery `.each()`. After all callbacks `.each()` initiates are done I'll have the value I need in `foo`.

```
var foo = -1;
window.each(function() {
  // abracadabra
  if (baz) foo = bar;
});
return foo; // this returns the incorrect foo as not all callbacks are complete
```

How do I get around this?

### Edit

One way to do it is have an infinite loop that keeps checking the count of callbacks and when all are complete return `foo`. I feel that's a bit hack-ish and there would be something better?

```
var allCallbacksDone = false;
var foo = -1;
window.each(function(index, element) {
  // abracadabra
  if (baz) foo = bar;
  if (index == window.length - 1) allCallbacksDone = true;
});
while (!allCallbacksDone) {
  continue;
}
return foo;
```

### Second Edit

`abracadabra` is a GET request to download remote images which is async.

Comment: What are you doing that's causing a callback?  A callback handler is a separate function and may be running asynchronously.  If it's just "each" that you're running then it won't exit until it has parsed all selected elements.

Comment: where are the async callbacks?  The `.each` function _isn't_ strictly a callback, it's just a function reference.  A callback is a function which is called _at some later point_ in response to some event.

Comment: The important question is what `abracadabra` is. If it's not asynchronous, then there's nothing asynchronous happening here. `each` is synchronous.

Comment: @lonesomeday `abracadabra` is a GET request to download remote images.

Comment: @lonesomeday: I should have specified that earlier. Too late, a -1 vote already. :(

Answer (score 4):

**YOU CANNOT RETURN VALUES FROM FUNCTIONS WHICH DEPEND ON THE RESULT OF ASYNCHRONOUS CALLS**

Sorry about the shouting, but it had to be said...

The best you can do is to have *another* callback be invoked once all of the others are done.

Anything else will result in busy loops., which will make the application non-responsive.

To resolve this (no pun intended), use jQuery's `deferred` objects:

```
var defArray = [];

window.each(function(index, element) {

    // create a deferred object and store it
    var d = $.Deferred();
    defArray.push(d);

    // trigger the image download 
    however you do it...

    // register a callback for the download completion
    // which "resolves" the deferred object
    someimg.onload = function() {
        d.resolve();

        // probably other actions needed here too
    }        
});

// now call _another_ function once _all_ of the deferreds are resolved
$.when.apply($, defArray).then(function() {
    // everything is done - do your calculations
});
```

Note that my first line still stands - you can't just wait for everything and then return the result - JS doesn't work that way.

Ideally you would create one addition deferred object, and your function return a `promise` based on that object, which your final callback will `resolve` with the result of the final calculation.

Comment: The anonymous function jQuery `.each()` calls has a GET request to download remote images which is async, right? I somehow need to know when all those threads are done executing. And then I'll know the largest image on the page.

Comment: Right, _now_ we're getting somewhere...  I'll amend.

Comment: I'm using imagemagick for node.js. There's a callback after the downloading of images. Can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var foo = -1;  // Don't need this now
var count = window.length;
window.each(function() {
  // abracadabra
  count--;
  if (count == 0) complete(bar);
});

function complete(value) {
//  everything is complete and value == bar
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set `foo` when everything is done. I want to return it after all of the callbacks are done.

Comment: Ah - I see.  I'll amend to suit.

Comment: Can you supply an example, rather than just a snippet?  I think I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: We need information about the callback.  Without knowing what you're doing there's no way to give example code.

Comment: The anonymous function that `.each()` calls is called the callback here, right? I was referring to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function check(callback) {
  var foo = -1, complete = false, count = window.length - 1, interval;
  window.each(function (index) {
    if (baz) foo = bar;
    complete = (index == count);
  });
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (complete) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback();
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

Call `check()` to run the `.each()` loop, providing a method as `callback` for when the task is complete.